# Nested for loops in Python

Tags: python

I'm newbie in Python 2.7 and currently have the following code:

```
Xtest_kernel=np.zeros((100,100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        Xtest_kernel[i,j]=math.exp((- numpy.linalg.norm(Xtrain[i,:]-Xtest[j,:])**2)/0.2)
```

Is there a faster way by using map function?

Comment: There are surely a variety of ways to do this with generators, list comprehensions, or `map` as you mention. What version of Python are you using? Could you produce a reduced/generic example of this code or tag or provide information about the libraries involved? I'm unfamiliar with whatever `Xtest_kernal` is, and that may affect the answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is some syntactic sugar for python that would look something like

```
Xtest_kernel = [[ Xtest_kernel[i,j]=math.exp((- numpy.linalg.norm(Xtrain[i,:]-Xtest[j,:])**2)/0.2) for j in range(100) ] for i in range(100) ]
```

if that is what you are looking for

Comment: That is an invalid Python syntax.

Comment: `Xtest_kernel= np.array([ math.exp((- np.linalg.norm(Xtrain[i,:]-Xtest[j,:])**2)/0.2) for i in range(100) for j in range(100) ]).reshape(100,100);
`
This is true, but performance is not better